# SubSonic and advanced keys/indexes

Tags: sqlite, orm, subsonic

Is there a way to create index or uniqe column when using SubSonic orm (declared in the same way as for example SubSonicPrimaryKey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible when using Migrations.

Read the cons section [in the docs](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/3.0_Migrations).

If you want that level of control over the created database then "migrations might not be for you".
You can always create the database [script] yourself if you want such things.